# HTML Element's color is wrong

Tags: html, css

```
element.style {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
front_layout.css (line 21)
Inherited from div#header
#header {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
front_layout.css (line 542)
Inherited from body
body {
    font: 75%/160% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

These are all the styles showed from firebug for this element.

This element's color is constantly something else, instead of white (visual and in computed part of firebug).

Why is this? What's overriding it's inherited value from #div header?

Edit: the element is a link. `<a float: left; font-weight: bold; margin-right: 8px" href="">About Us</a>`

Comment: Could you possibly share a stripped down snippet in jsFiddle?

Comment: Please supply some HTML markup to compare the CSS to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the default color for a link you are seeing. Add

```
#header a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

and your link will be white.

The color from the container div `#header` will not be applied to the containing `a` tag. You have to specify it explicitly.

Comment: How come it won't be applied? What's the general rule here (and why does firebug shows it if it's not applied?)

Comment: `a` tags have different states (can be adressed with pseudo classes like :visited and so on). These have higher priority than an inherited value from a container. I think, Firebug doesn't show these default values, because the shown colors differ from browser to browser. But it is in case a bit misleading to show the inherited value from the container in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

So the property `color` refers to the font color. `background-color` refers to the background color. Not sure if you were confusing those.

If it's font color related try adding !important after the color property and see if that overrides it. If so then it's likely a cascading issue and you need to see what other elements are being set. Do you have `a:link { color:red; }` somewhere that is causing issues. This can also happen if you have a bad closing tag.